# Redirect browser to login page with passport-saml

Tags: node.js, reactjs, single-sign-on, okta, passport-saml

I have an application where the front-end is ReactJs and the back-end is express.

I am trying to implement SSO with SAML2 and I use OKTA as the IDP.

```
    front-end is running on localhost:3000
    the back-end is running on localhost:4500
```

I use passport-saml to do the authentication process.

My login and callback functions are as follows.

```
app.get("/login", passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }), (req, res) => {
  res.end()
});


app.post("/callback", passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }), (req, res) => {
  return res.redirect('/home')
});
```

In React if when I call login API in the following way

```
 fetch(`/login`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(state => this.setState(state));
```

When I do that, I can see an API call to OKTA login page in the browser network tab but the browser does not redirect to the login page.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR**

When a user calls this API if the user is already signed in user should be landed on the home page of the browser or if the user is not already logged in the browser should be redirected to the login page.

what is the correct way of doing this?